# What is the best method for performing a lookup based on an API response? To then modify the JSON data passed to the API based on that lookup?

Tags: python, json, rest

I am new to Python, JSON, and API requests. I have spent time the past week doing small exercises and am now ready to dive in(well thought I was anyway). I would love to continue learning about all this to create my own personal projects in the future, but have felt discouraged today just trying to understand how to tackle my first project.

I am working with a GPS application that has an API. The end goal is to take a list of truck numbers given to me by someone in a CSV format, pass each truck numbers to the API or a stored dictionary/list to perform a lookup, as the truck number we use is different than the id of the truck that the API uses to identify the truck, convert the truck number to the ID, then pass that id to a new URL which then applies a tag in the API to that ID.

Generally this would be for around 70-80 trucks each day. I would then do the reverse at the end of each day to remove the tag from each id.

I am successful when simply entering the id number using this code below, and have tried watching several videos and documentation, but cannot wrap my head around how to do this with multiple trucks and converting from truck number to ID. Any and all assistance is appreciated. Apologies for my ignorance up front.

First I needed to find the id number of each truck in the csv based on the truck number. I performed the following code to retrieve all the trucks, and manually reviewed the response to find the id number for one truck.

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/659/users?FromIndex=0&PageSize=1000'
headers = {'Authorization': "YYY"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
###that prints out a list of each user and their variables, it looks like this
[{'trackPoint': {'position': {'altitude': YYYY, 'longitude': -YYYY, 'latitude': YYYY}, 'velocity': {'groundSpeed': 0.0, 'heading': 19.0}, 'utc': '2022-07-28T21:46:52Z', 'valid': True}, 'calculatedSpeed': 0.0, 'deviceActivity': '2022-07-28T21:46:50Z', 'lastTransport': 'udp', 'username': 'SW5151', 'name': '5151', 'surname': '', 'description': 'ASL Truck', 'email': '', 'devices': [{'id': 542, 'created': '0001-01-01T00:00:00', 'name': 'CalAmp LMU2600', 'hidePosition': False, 'proximity': 0.0, 'imei': 'YYYY', 'msisdn': {'raw': ''}, 'email': '', 'apn': '', 'gprsUsername': '', 'gprsPassword': '', 'lastIP': '', 'lastPort': 0, 'staticIP': '', 'staticPort': 0, 'protocolID': 'CalAmp', 'profileId': 0, 'protocolVersionID': 0, 'msgFieldDictionaryID': 39, 'deviceDefinitionID': 21, 'mobileNetworkID': 0, 'longitude': 0.0, 'latitude': 0.0, 'timeStamp': '0001-01-01T00:00:00', 'ownerID': 767, 'ownerUsername': '', 'ownerName': '', 'ownerEmail': '', 'devicePassword': '', 'oneWireVariables': []}], 'userTemplateID': 32, 'icon': {'iconOffsetX': 11, 'iconOffsetY': 19, 'iconGUID': 'c219b87971d82284a812198cb84eec69', 'rotatable': True}, 'id': 767}
###So the truck number is 5151 listed as name, the id is 767.
```

```
###Update Truck Tag Code, this code works as intended.
import requests
import json
url = 'https://YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/2259/users'
headers = {'Authorization': "YYY"}
#id below can be modified using the converted truck number to id
json_data = {
    'id':767,
}
req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
jsstring = json.dumps(req, indent=4)
print(jsstring)
```

Following along with a video, I was able to create a dictionary or a list? Honestly unsure which it creates. This would allow me to perhaps use a csv file to reference the id based on the truck number in the csv. Unsure on how to do that.

```
###create a reference of sort, stumped myself on this one
url = 'https://YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/659/users?FromIndex=0&PageSize=1000'
headers = {'Authorization': "YYY"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.text)

user_list = []
for user in data:
    name = user['name']
    id = user['id']
    user_conv = {
        'name': name,
        'id': id
    }
    user_list.append(user_conv)
#kinda got lost here on how to use my truck numbers to convert then pass back
```

From here I though maybe I should maybe a excel workbook to convert based on lookup, but feel I shouldnt, as the truck names could change, and my data would be out of date, vs polling the API first, creating the dict or list and moving from there.

Once again any input is appreciated, even if you want to make fun of me, as it is well deserved.

Comment: Where is the truck number in either of these codes?

Comment: The id in the first code was retrieved via the API by requesting all of the users in the system, and I then manually reviewed the results and found the corresponding id number. So the truck number was not used in the code for the update, as I dont have the proper way of converting it yet, it is listed in the json_data. The actual truck number is 1759, the id is 824.

Comment: Do you have a file (e.g. CSV) that contains the mapping between truck numbers and IDs? Turn that file into a dictionary, then in your loop you can convert the ID returned by the API to the corresponding truck number.

Comment: If this has to be done manually, the second script will have to display the IDs to the user, and ask them to provide the corresponding truck number.

Comment: I could certainly create the CSV that has all the truck numbers and the id. What is the method for turning that file into a dictionary?

Comment: Does not need to be done manually, would prefer it is not manual.

Comment: Note that `data = json.loads(r.text)` can be just `data = r.json()`.  That's built into `requests` responses.

Comment: This seems like something that could be accomplished by looping over all the trucks in your list, getting the id and then calling the api using a url that using string formatting for the truck id.

Comment: @Yorapios If it doesn't have to be done manually, how do you do it? Are they in a file, database, what?

Comment: @Barmar To clarify, I have not started to use this at all quite yet. I first tested I had the right code to perform the update and confirmed it worked by tracking down the id. 

I should also clarify I receive a CSV document daily that simply has one column with the truck numbers currently. Was not sure how to use it so I found the corresponding id by requesting a list of all the truck id from the API and found the match for the truck number I am testing with.

Comment: @maxrzaw That sounds like what I would like to do, but am unsure on how to do that.

Comment: There's still something missing in the question. How are you figuring out the corresponding IDs? If you can do it, what's preventing you from doing the same thing in the script?

Comment: @barmar, I am going to edit the question with how I was able to perform the initial lookup of id number. But that is part of the question, how can I automate the lookup to convert from truck number to ID. Give me just a moment.

Comment: @Barmar edit is complete

Comment: You're already doing what you need in your last script. `name` is the truck number, `id` is the truck ID. You could instead make it a dictionary instead of a list, where `id` is the key and `name` is the value, then you can use that in other code that needs to translate the ID to the truck number. From your question I didn't think the truck number was in the data from the API.

Comment: @Barmar My apologies for the miscommunication. You are right that I feel I am very close on the last script, but from what you see there, I have no idea how to feed in the CSV to provide the input and retrieve the id for each truck in the csv, then pass those ids into the middle script to update each id with the new tag. It is probably super basic, but have run into the wall there.

Comment: I don't understand how the CSV fits in. You already have the truck number in `user['name']` from the API.

Comment: @Barmar well the CSV contains the 70-90 trucks that I will need to update each day, I was thinking of using the CSV as an input to retrieve each id from the API or retrieve all at once then reference the dict/list. Vs running the script for each truck and manually changing the id each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a mapping between truck names and their associated IDs.

The first API endpoint seems to return a list of trucks, where each truck has a name and an ID. Just hit that endpoint, and use the response to construct a dictionary (what I'm calling `trucks` in this example) that maps a given truck name to its ID.

```
url = "https://YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/659/users?FromIndex=0&PageSize=1000"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "YYY"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()

trucks = {truck["name"]: truck["id"] for truck in response.json()}
```

You can then use `trucks` to look up the ID of a truck, given its name (I'm just doing a look-up for a single truck with a hardcoded truck name, but you can imagine doing this step in a loop while reading from a CSV of truck names, for example):

```
for current_truck_name in ["5151"]:
    current_truck_id = trucks[current_truck_name]
    print("The truck with name '{}' has the id '{}'".format(current_truck_name, current_truck_id))
```

This isn't that different from what you're doing in your last snippet. Where are you stuck exactly? How exactly would you use a truck's ID to make a request to another API endpoint to "apply a tag in the API to that ID"?

---

EDIT: Here is how you might read from a CSV file. Assuming you have a CSV file named `truck_names.csv`, which looks like this (a single column, one row per truck name):

```
truck_name
5151
1234
9999
```

Then you could do (assuming the `trucks` dictionary already exists at this point):

```
from csv import DictReader

with open("truck_names.csv", newline="") as file:
    reader = DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        truck_name = row["truck_name"]
        truck_id = trucks[truck_name]
        print(f"Performing tag update on truck with name '{truck_name}' (ID: '{truck_id}')...")

        url = "YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/2259/users"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": "YYY"
        }

        payload = {
            "id": truck_id
        }
        
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()

        print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for taking the time to answer. You are right very similar script. I am getting stuck on how to feed the csv in to your second script, then taking the results to feed into the first script in my question. Can you clarify how I would use the CSV instead of hardcoding a truck name? Ideally in your second script, I would retrieve the id from the dictionary for each truck number in the csv, then pass each id that returns into the second script in my question. Second snippet not the first snippet.

Comment: `
import requests
import json
url = 'https://YYY.YYY.com/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/46/tags/2259/users'
headers = {'Authorization': "YYY"}
##below is where the id is inserted
json_data = {
    'id':824,
}
req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
jsstring = json.dumps(req, indent=4)
print(jsstring)
`
So we would feed each id into this script to perform the tag update

Comment: Trying to use the code markdown didnt work, RIP. My b.

Comment: Paul you are the man. This performed exactly as I had hoped. I am going to review this thoroughly to ensure I understand how it is functioning, and may comment here if I have any clarifying questions. Thank you very much for your assistance.,